# php curl_exec die and exit script and show white screen

Tags: php, curl

this is my code:
when i try to connect to whm/Cpanel to add new account this issue occure but when i try to delete a user from whm/cpanel it works perfect.
my problem is curl_exec line die and show me blank white screen there isn't any error on the page and curl_error didn't return anything codes after curl_exec didn't run at all.

Thanks for your answers

```
$curl = curl_init();
# Create Curl Object
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
# Allow certs that do not match the domain
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
# Allow self-signed certs
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
# Return contents of transfer on curl_exec
$header[0] = "Authorization: WHM $cpanel_user:" . preg_replace("'(\r|\n)'", "", $whmhash);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1800);
# Remove newlines from the hash
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
# Set curl header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $command);
# Set your URL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, FALSE);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
if( ! $result = curl_exec($curl))
{
    trigger_error(curl_error($curl));
} 

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
# Execute Query, assign to $result
if ($result == false) {
    error_log("curl_exec threw error \"" . curl_error($curl) . "\" for $query");
}
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Are you sure you set `error_reporting()` to  `E_ALL` for testing purposes? And enabled `display_errors` in your vhost/.htaccess conf? If you get a blank page this sounds like `display_errors` is set to `off`.

Comment: You need to take a look at your logs.

Comment: error_reporting() allready seted to E_ALL Thanks for your remind

Comment: i also try to set verbose but it didn't output any result
    $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was nginx that didn't allow the response came back to my code.
by disabling nginx on server that working on proxy mode for apache it solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should use curl_errno to check if there was any error with curl

Replace this

```
if( ! $result = curl_exec($curl))
{
    trigger_error(curl_error($curl));
}
```

By

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);
// Check for errors and display the error message
if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    trigger_error("cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}");
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-strerror.php

Comment: Both versions should work. According to the php doc page about `curl_exec()`:  However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Comment: Still the same curl_exec die and other code didn't execute and run

Comment: Try to put `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);` it may be the reason why you don't have any error displayed

Comment: I try it but there isn't any result again

Comment: @phpniki we could discuss this more in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61254/php-curl-exec-die-and-exit-script-and-show-white-screen